# Wordpress automatically adds links to uploaded images

Tags: php, images, uploads, media, gallery

Wordpress automatically adds the link to every image I upload within Media. And then I can’t find a way to remove it. How can I upload images without links or just remove it? There is just no option to choose whether to upload with link or without. I tried many plugins for that but none seems to be working. This happens when I use uploaded images in default Gallery widget by Wordpress. I also tried this code, but nothing. Code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );
function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
$content =
preg_replace(
array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
'{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
array('<img','" />'),
$content
);
return $content;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the link? What is the end goal?

Comment: @disinfor Because now I can click on the image and it takes me to another page. I dont want images to be clickable

Comment: If you use Wordpress/Yoast SEO (and who doesn't) then this is option is available in the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You adjust that when you insert the image into the post, not when you upload it.

When you upload the image, you will be looking at it on the Media Library page. On the right hand side is a column that says "ATTACHMENT DETAILS". Scroll down on that, and look for "ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS".

The field you're looking for is called "Link To" and you want to set it to be "None" before you click the "Insert into Post" button.

[image]